# What are the pitfalls of using SVGZs instead of SVGs?

Tags: html, graphics, svg, vector-graphics

I recently started using svg images in my sites. Some of them are complex and quite big, so I've started compressing them. They compress really well.

Why would one ever **not** use SVGZs (instead of the uncompressed version)? Are there well-known pitfalls that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your webserver sets the proper Content-Encoding HTTP header it should work in all browsers that support SVG.

The one pitfall I know of is if you want to be able to open the svgz files from disk locally  (that is: without using a webserver). That doesn't work in all browsers.

Also if your svg files are big, then you should consider preprocessing them with [SVG Scour](http://www.codedread.com/scour/) or similar. It's rather common to see vector graphics editors such as Illustrator and Inkscape output display-redundant data in the files (binary blobs or custom xml markup).

Comment: "As long as your webserver sets the proper Content-Encoding HTTP header it should work in all browsers that support SVG." Is this why Chrome (latest) gives a warning "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml." ?

Comment: Good question, maybe ask that one separately? (or bugreport it to http://bugs.webkit.org?)

Answer (score 0):

Is it for desktop browsers, mobile? I know Opera supports SVGZ natively since 8.0 at least (maybe even earlier).

What server? Apache, IIS? You might have to configure it and/or mess with .htaccess. Here's a howto for Apache: http://kaioa.com/node/45

Keep in mind that the server might be already serving your content compressed, if your client supports it, as SVGZ is just a normal SVG with gzip compression applied.

Comment: Desktop browsers - according to my employer's policy, the sites only have to work on IE, Chrome and FF. I have looked at Opera and Safari, but they seem not to handle SVGs in the same way as the other three browsers... IIS server.

Comment: Safari and Chrome should have identical handling (unless it's an old version of Safari, naturally).